# How can I add a page that shows posts from a single category?

Tags: posts, categories, pages

Is it possible to add a page that shows posts for a certain category?  Do I need to create a page and have it redirect to `http://site.com/category/myposts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this? Menus --> Select an Category --> Add to Menu. Click Save! The link to this page should be available on your menu!

Comment: On the menu editor page, it says: "The current theme does not natively support menus, but you can use the Custom Menu widget to add any menus you create here to the theme’s sidebar."  I'd like to have my page show up on the top tab bar rather than a sidebar - do I need to change themes to accomplish this then, or is there another way?

Comment: Yes your theme need a Custom menu. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu